# Issue with certbot ssl installation with django application

Tags: python, django, ssl, ssl-certificate, certbot

I am trying to install SSL certificate using certbot. I have an Django application running on Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine. I have followed [this](https://certbot-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) documentation on how to get ssl for django application but I get an error

> certbot: error: unrecognized arguments:
>   --certbot-django-auth-key-directory ~/.ssh/certbot/

I have done everything this documentation says but still I do not know what i am doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: shouldnt it be ` --certbot-django-auth-key-directory=~/.ssh/certbot/`

Comment: Can you post the full command line you're running.

Comment: certbot certonly -d example.com \
                 -a certbot-django:auth \
                 --certbot-django-auth-key-directory=~/.ssh/certbot/ \
                 --certbot-django:auth-username=certbot \
                 --certbot-django:auth-public-ip-logging-ok

Error I'm Facing: "certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: --certbot-django-auth-key-directory ~/.ssh/certbot/"
I'm not getting this "unrecognized arguments" I have tried re-installing certbot and certbot-django.

Comment: This might be a plugin which i'm missing and I don't know how to manually install it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace --certbot-django-auth-key-directory ~/.ssh/certbot/ with
--certbot-django:auth-key-directory ~/.ssh/certbot/